# stateless authentication and permissions in the JWT token

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, jwt, amazon-cognito, claims-based-identity

1. Users in the applications have permissions based on the groups they are in
2. We would like to store the list of groups a user is in, in the JWT token
3. When a user gets added or removed from the groups, that effectively means the permissions change and this is what should happen at the user's end:

   If they have been removed entirely from the system, the user immediately  is kicked back out to the login screen

   If they have just been removed from a group, for example, the user is not kicked out

   They are notified that their rights have been updated, they are told to please refresh the page

   when the user refreshes, they stay on the page they are looking at

   If the user is on a screen they no longer have access to, they are sent to the home page

**1. We have so far been writing REST APIs that are all stateless but this seems to break that. What is the best way to achieve it?
2. If we were to keep it simple and ensure statelessness, What's the best approach?**

Answer (score 2):

With stateless authentication your ID token which contains your group information, isn't renewed until it expires (usually an hour). You can reduce this duration to 5 minutes. This would be the simplest way to make sure any update to group is reflected on the front end quickly. These tokens are independent and cannot be revoked once they are issued. Even if you run the global sign out API call or the forget device API call, only the refresh token is revoked, while the ID and access tokens are still valid until they expire.

The requirements you mention aren't compatible with a stateless authentication method. Sure, you can create a "hacky" flow where you have a database that records the id of users who are kicked out and before every call it checks the database but it would be a lot of unnecessary work and you would be defeating the whole point of using stateless authentication.

My suggestion, if you want to keep using cognito, is to reduce the expiration time of all tokens to the minumum. You can also eliminate refresh tokens from your flow but that would mean user needs to sign in every 5 minutes.
But if you really need to implement this, I would suggest using stateful authentication methods.

Comment: If I were to use IoT, would it be a topic per tenant or a topic per group per tenant, or a topic per user?